# Web server becomes unresponsive while making multiple cURL requests in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

(Edited for clarity)

In a CakePHP 4 controller I have a foreach loop within which I do the following.

```
$ch = curl_init($requestConfig['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonBody);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$curlError = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

In other words, I'm making one API request after the other. Nothing is forked or done in parallel.

The only additional thing is that before and after the curl call, I make a simple mysql request to register that the API request has started and then that it's finished. I have no reason to believe this is causing any issue.

Before entering the loop I do the following, to avoid locking the session.

```
$this->getRequest()->getSession()->close()
```

Before upgrading from CakePHP 3, I was using `session_write_close()`.

In the browser I poll the database every 5 seconds to see the progress.

**The problem**

Before upgrading from CakePHP 3 and PHP 7 (to 8.2), this was running without issues. It would happily chug through 100+ requests.

But after the upgrade, after 8–12 iterations, the web server stops responding. What I mean by this is that all the polling requests are left as "pending" in the browser network tab. It also means that if I open the CakePHP application in a new tab, it will just sit there spinning and not respond.

However, the background processes making the API request still runs to completion, which I can see from log entries.

Am I somehow not closing the cURL resource properly? Or is there some issue with opening and closing a new one with every iteration? Again, I'm running them sequentially in one single loop.

Comment: This sounds like something which ought to run as a background process anyway, rather than during a web request.

Comment: It kind of does, in the sense that it runs in an iframe, and the iframe has a javascript which polls the database for progress. Since it abandons the session it doesn't affect the rest of the app. This might not be ideal, but the issue is that it was working perfectly. It handled 100+ API request running for an hour or so without issues. But now it becomes unresponsive, and I'm trying to figure out why. From what I remember it happened when upgrading to PHP 8 and CakePHP 4.

Comment: The polling part can be on the Web, jut there's no need for the actual processing part to be

Comment: Are you saying that the polling part is what is breaking down? Are there any errors in the logs, or in the browser tools? We don't have a lot to go on here, and we can't access your environment obviously

Comment: Sorry I left out an important part. It's not just the polling requests but all requests get stuck. So if I open a second tab and just try to load any part of the application there, this also gets stuck. The strange thing is that it's not immediate, as it would be with a session locking issue. So initially everything works fine, but after around 10 API requests, the main script keeps chugging along but all other requests are stuck.

Comment: Every time you fire off one of these requests via iframe you're using up a web worker, both in your HTTP server [apache, nginx, etc] as well as FPM if you're using that. With a list of 150 objects I would wager that you're using up all the available workers and leaving nothing available for _anyone_ to use, not just your user as in the case of session locking. This is something that should definitely be running as a background task. I would suggest using a queue/worker model to keep the workload manageable rather than simply forking off 100+ background processes to become zombies.

Comment: So just to be clear, I'm only sending exactly one request to the web server, which in turn runs a loop and in each iteration opens and closes a curl resource. The only additional requests are the ones polling the progress, but these shouldn't be problematic, right? They are just simple GET requests. At which point am I forking background processes?

Comment: Given the lack of code in your question I assumed from your description that you were creating a number of background requests with iframes. If it's just the one iframe then there's not enough info in your posts/comments to do more than speculate even more broadly. While it be helpful to see the code of what fires this curl iframe task, as well as the more complete code of that task itself beyond simple curl boilerplate, it would still be difficult to determine the cause of the nebulous "server stops responding" without more detailed troubleshooting of the server itself, which only you can do.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'll try to edit the question to be more precise! 
The strange thing here is that the "boilerplate" curl code really is all that's going on. There is essentially just a foreach loop, and within that loop the curl code is executed. Other than that it's just code to format the request. By "server stops responding" I mean just that, that any new tabs I open just sit there spinning. And that any AJAX calls are left at "pending" in the browser network tab.

Comment: I've edited for clarity. Thank you all for your continued help with this!

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant but the docs say that [curl_close()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php) no longer has any effect, since PHP 8.0.0. Are the curl requests to the same CakePHP app or a completely separate system?

Comment: It does very much sound like either a) you've ended up running too many AJAX requests simultaneously (it can happen if lots of users are using your polling functionality at once, and/or the requests occur too frequently so they overlap), and/or b) the long-running web process which performs the cURL requests is using too many server resources and so blocking everything else. PHP is annoyingly bad at asynchronous / parallel programming. Is the API that cURL is calling on another server, or the same one that PHP runs on?

Comment: Instead of initialising multiple curl sessions, why not just `curl_reset()` at the end of each iteration? Assuming they are all going to the same server, this will reuse the existing connection.

Comment: @user1191247 this was news to me about curl_close no longer working in PHP 8. If I'm no longer able to close the curl session, is it automatically freed? This sounds like it could be the problem.

The reason I'm creating a new session for each request is that several different parts of the application can make this type of API request. So the whole request cycle is contained within a function which can be called in different contexts.

It sounds like potentially I need to factor out creating the curl session to its own function/module.

Comment: The API is on a different server.

Comment: As you are overwriting `$ch` with a new `CurlHandle` in each iteration, the previous `CurlHandle` will get _"cleaned up"_, as there are no remaining references. Reusing the same `CurlHandle` for each iteration will just remove the overhead of establishing a new connection and performing handshakes for each request. This is not the cause of your server not responding to the progress polling requests. To confirm this is not a session locking issue, are you able to access the CakePHP app via an incognito window, while the other polling requests are pending?

Comment: The creating and closing of the curl session is encapsulated in a function which is called from within the foreach loop. So $ch isn't actually overwritten, it's defined within the function. Is it possible that could cause the sessions to persist for longer than they should? My plan right now is to create the session only once, before entering the loop, then passing it to the function where it is currently created, then closing after finishing the loop.